# Can one set default values for Discriminated Union types?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, qualified-name

I implemented a Discriminated Union type that would be used to select a function:

```
type BooleanCombinator =
    | All
    | Some
    | None
    | AtLeast of int
    | MoreThan of int
    | NotMoreThan of int
    | LessThan of int
    | ExactlyOne
    | ExactlyTwo
    | AllButOne
    | AllButTwo

let boolToInt (b: bool) : int = if b then 1 else 0

let combineBooleans (combinator : BooleanCombinator)
                    (bools      : bool list)
                                : bool =

        let n = List.sumBy boolToInt bools

        match combinator with
        | BooleanCombinator.All -> List.forall id bools
        | BooleanCombinator.Some -> bools |> List.exists id
        | BooleanCombinator.None -> bools |> List.exists id |> not
        | BooleanCombinator.AtLeast i -> n >= i
        | BooleanCombinator.MoreThan i -> n > i
        | BooleanCombinator.NotMoreThan i -> n <= i
        | BooleanCombinator.LessThan i -> n < i
        | BooleanCombinator.ExactlyOne -> n = 1
        | BooleanCombinator.ExactlyTwo -> n = 2
        | BooleanCombinator.AllButOne -> n = bools.Length - 1
        | BooleanCombinator.AllButTwo -> n = bools.Length - 2
```

This looked Ok to me but the compiler started to look at all instances of `Some` and `None` as belonging to this DU, instead of the `Option` DU.

I do not want to go through all of my code replacing `Some` with `Option.Some` and `None` with `Option.None`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that unqualified `Some` and `None` are actually `Option.Some` and `Option.None`?

Or should I just give different names to these DU cases, like `AtLeastOne` and `ExactlyZero`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark your DU with `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute.

This means that you will be required to qualify the case name with the type whenever you use it in the code - which is something you do now anyway in your `match` expression.

That way an unqualified `Some` would still be resolved to mean `Option.Some`, despite the fact that you reuse the name.

It's a useful technique to know when you want to use a snappy name for a DU case - like `None`, `Yes`, `Failure` etc. - that by itself would be ambiguous or confusing to the reader (or the compiler, for that matter).

Comment: This is actually better than my answer. I totally forgot about `RequireQualifiedAccess`.

Answer (score 6):

The general rule for resolving name collisions in F# is "last declaration wins". Because your custom DU is declared after `Option`, its constructors `Some` and `None` win over those of `Option`.

But this rule offers a way to fix the problem: you just need to "reassert" the declarations after your custom DU:

```
type Bogus = Some of int | None

let g = function Some _ -> 42 | None -> 5
let x = Some 42

let inline Some a = Option.Some a
let inline None<'a> = Option.None : 'a option
let (|Some|None|) = function | Option.Some a -> Some a | Option.None -> None

let f = function Some _ -> 42 | None -> 5
let y = Some 42
```

If you inspect the types of `g`, `x`, `f`, and `y` in the above code:

```
> g
g : Bogus -> int

> f
f : 'a option -> int

> x
Bogus

> y
int option
```

The function `g` and value `x` were inferred to have type `Bogus -> int` and `Bogus` respectively, because `Some` and `None` in their bodies refer to `Bogus.Some` and `Bogus.None`.

The function `f` and value `y` were inferred to have `Option`-related types, because `Some` and `None` in their bodies refer to the `Some` function and the `(|Some|None|)` active pattern that I defined just above.

Of course, this is a rather hacky way to restore status quo. This will convince the compiler, but humans will still have a hard time reading your code. I suggest you rename the cases of your DU instead.